# TypeScript: how to define a type that returns a intersection of an arbitrary number of other types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying write a type that returns a intersection of an arbitrary number of other types. Something like that

```js
type TypeofStatementIntersections<CL extends Function[]> = { [SN in keyof CL]: (builder: CL[SN]) => CL[SN] }[number] extends
    (arg1: infer IT) => void ? IT : never;

function MixStaticReferencesOf<T1 extends Function[]>(...builder: T1): TypeofStatementIntersections<T1> {

    return Object.assign({});
}

class C1 {

    p1 = 1;

    static staticProp1: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;
    
    static staticMethod1() {

    }

}

class C2 {

    static staticProp2: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;

    static staticMethod2() {
        return C2.staticProp2;
    }

    method2() {
        return C2.staticProp2;
    }

}

class C3 {

    static staticProp3: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;

    static staticMethod3() {

    }

}

const MixedStaticReferences = MixStaticReferencesOf(C1, C2, C3); // : typeof C1 & typeof C2 & typeof C3
```

It works to mix static references, but I want an another type to reference instance mixing. I'd like to define a type that returns `C1 & C2 & C3 & ...`, the example define the fellow return type `typeof C1 & typeof C2 & ...`

Is it possible?

Comment: Why isn't `typeof C1 & typeof C2 ` correct ? You want to mix the statics.. `typeof T` represents the static side of a class `T`, `T` is the instance type.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sorry, I updated the post. I want an another type to reference instance mixing instead of static references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a few pieces here.

First you need a type for constructor functions, which will accept any function that can be called with `new`:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any
```

Then you need to be able to merge a union into an intersection. I like this one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

Last piece we need is [the `InstanceType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype),

```
const c1: InstanceType<typeof C1> = new C1() // same as type `C1`
```

Putting that together you can type your function pretty simply:

```
const MixedInstanceReferences =
  <T extends Constructor[]>(...args: T):
    UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<T[number]>> => {
  return {} as any // TODO: implementation
}
```

It accepts a list of constructor functions, converts them to a union with `T[number]`, gets the instance type of any member of that union with `InstanceType`, and then merge that union into an intersection with `UnionToIntersection`

Which does what you want:

```
const allCs = MixedInstanceReferences(C1, C2, C3) // C1 & C2 & C3
allCs.p1
allCs.method2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=14&pln=37&pc=1#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-V2BDz4jihq1ehwJp3MWd5x4d1gi4ZZXV1T0fT9ANrX4INTyoe93TtWRnyXfhRmsAAjeQV1DcMNy2YYxgmMJF2TLdoFxaB3QAeQAEUYutrGwEBZFsX03H5SIdy-RcQBAWAYAIQ9jxUFDlQva8GxGe8IECBAABoEnU+5QnohBoAAMgSfS4DudAwBEsTzFwUzzIsVYenWIA)

Comment: Thnaks so much. But, if I want to use just like that `const allCs: UnionToIntersection<C1, C2, C3> = new AnAnyConstructor(C1, C2, C3);`. How should `UnionToIntersection` type look?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I discover how to do that.
Drawing on colleague Wayne's response...
I needed to change this peace

```js
... ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

to

```js
... ((k: infer I) => void) ? new () => I : never
```

Now, the function is constructible.

```js
const ConstructibleFunction = MixedInstanceReferences(C1, C2, C3)
const instance = new ConstructibleFunction
instance.p1; // ok
```

I got this by looking at the effect of the static property [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) inherited from the `Function` class.

Thanks.